# What's the difference of EntityManager (setHint) Read-Only and Session Read-Only?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to load some entities as read-only, I noticed that I have some options to do that, like @Immutable and also read-only in query.

My main question is what's the difference between setHint:

```
    getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT p FROM Post p").setHint(QueryHints.READ_ONLY, true).getResultList();
```

And setReadOnly:

```
    Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Post p");
    query.setReadOnly(true);
    query.list();
```

Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

same thing:
the hibernate implementation of javax.persistence.TypedQuery.setHint(String, Object)(org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setHint(String, Object)) is calling  indirectly the org.hibernate.Query.setReadOnly(boolean):

```
org.hibernate.Query.setReadOnly(boolean)
called by org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImplapplyReadOnlyHint(boolean)
called by org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImplsetHint(String, Object)
called by org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setHint(String, Object)
```